# Substituting in values in a cubic equation

Tags: cubics

I am stuck on the following problem. I also mean to say greet you with a Hello! but for some reason it won't save it haha.

This problem was part of my homework, which is now past due and I have received partial credit for. The answer was released and I am trying to understand it.

I am completely stuck on the "Solving the equation $1+ \frac{2\sqrt{21}}{9} = (3a+a\sqrt{21})^3 $ for $a$" part. No matter how I break it down, I can't get that answer. Also, it seems like the $a=-6$ as the coefficient of the $x^2$ term has nothing to do with this part of the problem. Can someone explain please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is confusing for them to use $a$ in the hint, since it coincides with the coefficient of the $x^2$ term, and has nothing to do with the purpose of the hint.

Now the hint was

\begin{align}1+ \frac{2\sqrt{21}}{9} &= (3a+a\sqrt{21})^3 \\&=a^3(3+\sqrt{21})^3
\\&= a^3(3^3+3\cdot3^2\sqrt{21}+3\cdot3\sqrt{21}^2+\sqrt{21}^3)
\\&=a^3(27+27\sqrt{21}+189+21\sqrt{21})
\\&=a^3(216+48\sqrt{21})
\\\leadsto a^3=\frac 19\frac{9+2\sqrt{21}}{216+48\sqrt{21}}&=\frac19\frac1{24}=\frac1{216}\end{align} (Factor the denominator and the numerator appears so a cancellation takes place)

which gives $a=\dfrac16$. Hence $1+ \dfrac{2\sqrt{21}}{9} = (3a+a\sqrt{21})^3 = \left(\dfrac12+\dfrac16\sqrt{21}\right)^3$.

This hint is only used to simplify the root

$$u=\sqrt[3]{1+ \frac{2\sqrt{21}}{9}}$$

Comment: sharp approach!

Comment: @imranfat What do you mean by "A conjugate is used to take out the radical in the numerator"?

Comment: thank you so much! I honestly would never have approached it that way. Did in a few lines what I was trying to understand for a couple hours!

Comment: @player3236 "What do you mean by : A conjugate is used to take out the radical in the numerator?"
He means that 
$$\frac{9 + 2\sqrt{21}}{216 + 48\sqrt{21}} 
\times \frac{9 - 2\sqrt{21}}{9 - 2\sqrt{21}}
~=~ \frac{-3}{1944 + 432\sqrt{21} - 432\sqrt{21} - 2016}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 I certainly did not approach it that way. I simply observed that $216+48\sqrt{21} = 24(9+2\sqrt {21})$.

Comment: Interesting situation.  First of all, I didn't notice the point that you are making, which is certainly the best approach.  Second of all, I got confused - I assumed (wrongly) that you were **not** the person who created the answer and that you were questioning what a specific line in the answer intended.  So, I assumed that you were the OP, and simply got out my calculator to answer.  My bad.

Comment: @user2661923 A perplexing situation indeed (usually people point out my mistakes/suggest improvements in the comments). I know the radicals can be eliminated since it was given as a hint.

Comment: Of course, I see it now. Simple factoring (I edited). I did it with a conjugate, but obviously simply factoring is much better